# why does vc++ 2017 show errors instead of warnings for C4297?

Tags: visual-c++

Our VC++ 2017 code build fails with errors such as C4297. When I google these, I see them as warnings. I am wondering if I am missing compiler switches in my build

Comment: Perhaps, you have treat warnings as errors on. A perfect tool to grief lazy coworkers. Bu that one technically right... your code is non-C++11 compliant if it trips that

Comment: I agree with your assertion. However, VC++ compile also displays error C4244 on standard include files such as algorithm. They should be warnings only.

Comment: usually when that happens, something wrong with use of highlighted template (instantiation), e.g. not fitting the type offered by user smoothly. THis happens not only with VS abut with GCC as well. A typical case described here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper - using `transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper)` in fact is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that a third party header file has pragma definitions that flag these warnings as errors. #pragma warning (error : 4290) is an example of such an entry. Removed this header file and the errors are gone.

Comment: Third party library might have a good reason for that. E.g. it does something with run-time library APi or stack tracing and  a possible exception in constructor might cause catastrophic failures.